# How can we attach an event with the radio input?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am working with Ionic Framework on a mobile app. I have a filter in AlertController which I am using to filter item. Following is the code snippet:

```
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create();
alert.setTitle('Categories');
alert.addInput({
      type: 'radio',
      label: this.allCategories[i].categoryName,
      value: this.allCategories[i].id,
      checked: true
});

alert.addButton({
    text: 'Ok',
    handler: data => {
     //Filter Items by categories.
    }
  });
```

My question is that how can we attach an event with the radio input? Currently the items are filtered on "OK" button click of AlertController which is working fine but I would like to do it with an item is clicked.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just curious couldnt you use a modal for this?

Comment: @suraj nope. I should use AlertController.